# Why does malloc provoke memory corruption here?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, rpc, memory-corruption

I keep getting the following error:

```
*** Error in `./vice': malloc(): memory corruption: 0x08e77530 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The relevant code is:

```
open_result *
open_file_1_svc(open_args *argp, struct svc_req *rqstp)
{
    static open_result  result;
    int obtained_fd;
    int just_read;
    int total_read = 0;
    int max_bytes_read = 1024;
    char *ptr_file;
    char *pathName = "MyFiles/"; // strlen = 8
    int toReserve;

    xdr_free((xdrproc_t)xdr_open_result, (char *)&result);

    // Construct full name of the file (in "MyFiles")
    toReserve = strlen(argp->fname) + strlen(pathName) + 1; // "\0"
    char *fullName = malloc(toReserve*sizeof(char));
    fullName = strdup(pathName);
    fullName = strcat(fullName, argp->fname);

    // Call to open in POSIX
    obtained_fd = open(fullName, argp->flags);

    result.fd = obtained_fd;

    /* If there was an error while reading, the error code will be sent, but not
       the file (it might not even exist) */
    if (obtained_fd < 0) {
        result.characters = "";
        result.number_characters = 0;
    }
    /* If the file opening was successful,
       both the fd and the file will be sent */
    else {
        char *file_just_read = malloc(max_bytes_read * sizeof(char)); // This is the problem
        ptr_file = file_just_read;

        /* Reading the file byte by byte */
        while((just_read = read(obtained_fd, ptr_file, max_bytes_read)) > 0) {
            total_read += just_read;
            file_just_read = realloc(file_just_read, (total_read+max_bytes_read) * sizeof(char));
            ptr_file = file_just_read + total_read;
        }
        result.characters = file_just_read;
        result.number_characters = total_read;
    }
    return &result;
}
```

Let me explain what the code does. This is a server named "vice" which communicates with its clients via RPC. This function is supposed to receive "open_args" and return "open_result". These are defined in the "vice.x" file. The relevant part of this file is:

```
struct open_args {
    string fname<>;
    int flags;
};

struct open_result {
    string characters<>;
    int number_characters;
    int fd;
};
```

open_file_1_svc is supposed to try to open a file with the name given in argp->fname in the directory MyFiles. If open is successful, open_file_1_svc will attempt to copy the contents of the file in result.characters, sending a copy of the contents of the file to the client this way. The number_characters will allow me to know if there are any null bytes in between.

The error I'm getting appears when I attempt to allocate some memory for the part of the file I'm about to read.

I've been reading about this type of error, but I don't understand what's wrong with this particular case.

Comment: `char *fullName = malloc(toReserve*sizeof(char));
    fullName = strdup(pathName);
    fullName = strcat(fullName, argp->fname);` First you leak memory, then your strcat() writes beond the allocated size. HINT: Your `toReserve` is computed, but not used.

Comment: Debugging 101: Can you isolate the error? Produce a complete, executable program that reliably triggers the observed problem, then cutting away bits of logic until you end up with the minimum amount of code, ideally just a `main()` using a couple of hard-coded values? This is the thing about giving a fish and teaching to fish, if you get my drift...

Comment: Note that `strdup` isn't part of standard C, consider using `strcpy` or `memcpy` instead

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem ... or snprintf() for path-construction.

Comment: @joop got it right. The first line (`malloc()`) allocates enough memory for what you're trying to do and makes `fullName` point to that. But the next line (`strdup()`) makes `fullName` point to a *different* memory location just big enough for `pathName` -- the original memory allocation is lost. The third line (`strcat()`) then invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @user3121023 No, although `malloc` is not idiomatic C++, it is what `new` uses behind the scenes.

Comment: Thank you very much to all of you. I'm sorry for creating so much inconvenience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`malloc` does not "provoke" the corruption; `malloc` *detects* it.

This error is telling you that something had scribbled over the heap meta data *before* `malloc` was called (this time); you probably have a buffer overrun.

Both `malloc` calls in this code are before anything writes to memory, so the overrun is most likely elsewhere. (I've not done a detailed check that *this* code is right, but it's after-the-fact here.)

---

Edit: I missed the implicit `malloc` call inside the `strdup`. This will cause an overrun because the duplicated string has a smaller allocation. I think you mean `strcpy`, not `strdup`.

Comment: OP really is using `strdup`, because `strcpy` would require 2 arguments to be passed

Comment: Well, obviously `strdup` wouldn't compile with two parameters.